# How to deploy Railo 3.2.3 on Resin 4.0.15?

Tags: railo, resin

I've just discovered that all the install guides for railo+resin assume you're installing the obsolete 3.1.2 bundle (railo-3.1.0.012-resin-3.1.2-without-jre.zip). I have Resin 4 installed now, what is the process for deploying the Railo WAR / JAR's (under linux)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be nearly identical to setting up Railo on Resin 3.1. Have you tried it?

http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/documentation/installation/railo-resin-apache/

Comment: I was looking for instructions specific to 4.0 so I missed that guide. I've already switched to Jetty and AJP (I no longer trust mod_caucho because it's given me too much grief) so I won't be testing it but your answer is probably valid and noone else has posted so I've awarded it.